# difference between ffmpeg vs live555

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, live555, mpeg2-ts

Does anyone knows what's the main difference between `live555` and `ffmpeg`. It seems that both are capable of doing video streaming. Is it that `live555` does it in `RTSP`, while `ffmpeg` does it in `mpeg-2` transport stream ? Thanks, Ran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply:

- FFMPEG is a library for encoding and decoding video/audio
- Live555 is a library for streaming already encoded movies/audio and reading in streams.

Yes some compiled/pre-built versions of FFMPEG can stream video but it's main use is for encoding and decoding video/audio.

Live555 has a quite elaborate set of tools to allow streaming over a number of different protocols and different types of streams (not just RTSP, and it can also do mpeg-2 streaming). The core Live555 library does not allow you to encode or decode movies, it is simply a set of tools for streaming video/audio only. Some compiled/pre-built versions may allow you to perform encoding/decoding but it is using some library other than live555.

Comment: I find that ffmpeg can also convert from raw video such as H264 raw  to MPEG-2 TS:
ffmpeg -i $source_file -vcodec libx264 test.ts

Comment: Yes you are correct. FFMPEG can handle raw streams as well as encapsulated streams. Your example would decode the raw H264 stream and re-encode to an MPEG2 stream encapsulated in a TS container. FFMPEG is quite versatile.

Comment: for streaming, Do you think libav is a better solution than live555 ?

Answer (score 2):

They are built using some of the same libs and in general ffmpeg may be used more for transcoding and c interface to libs used in transcoding.

Live555 is good for RTSP protocol among lots of other things.

Look first to ffmpeg for transcode related stuff and to live555 for streaming .